# How to run Python script on Ubuntu, Windows and MAC

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu

I'm making Python software using wx GUI library but was wondering how to run this script on different OS's. For example, do I need to create executable installation file or bat file on Windows and sh file in Ubuntu?

I've got `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the file and I can seem to run it by actually double clicking it and clicking it on "RUN" on prompt window but I would like it to be more professional as the users are not programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being used to run python scripts on both linux and Windows environments, I know that you can use the same script for both environments. 
Keep using your shebang in Linux, it won't be procesed in windows (as it is actually a comment :).

Once Python is installed in Windows, you can actually simply double click on the script (it will run by default in a cmd window), run it using the cmd or launch it in idle.

If you want to develop python scripts on windows however, you'll need some more tools :).

If you want to be more professional (and prevent your users to modify the code :), you can still think about creating an exe file : http://www.lyxia.org/blog/developpement/python/creez-des-executables-46
(warning, french inside), by using pyinstaller http://www.pyinstaller.org/ . Works for windows and linux